# CakePHP Model Assocation

Tags: cakephp, database-connection, model-associations, cakephp-model

Trying to make a model association on cake php but the table either self references or gets errors.

I have 2 tables 'matches' and 'teams'.

matches have the following attributes:
id,
team_1,
team_2,
game_id,
time,

teams have the following attributes:
id,
team_name,
game_id,

I am trying to make the Match.Team_1 and Match.Team_2 relate to the appropriate Team.id

A match has to have exactly 2 teams, and never more and never less.

I've tried using 2 hasOne relations and that just got a self referencing table. I am trying to use Matches hasMany Teams association now with a 'limit' => '2' to have exactly 2 teams.  However it is using the match.id to find the matching team instead of using team_1 and team_2.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
class Match extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
    'Team' => array(
        'className' => 'Team',
        'foreignKey' => 'id',
        'limit' => '2',
    )
 );
}
```

gives output array of

```
[Match] => Array
            (
                [id] => 33
                [team_1] => 4
                [team_2] => 2
                [match_time] => 2015-02-13 12:00:00
                [game_id] => 0
            )

        [Team] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 33
                        [team_name] => ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the following:

First rename fields team_1 and team_2 in home_id and guest_id

Then create association:

```
class Match extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
'HomeTeam' => array(
    'className' => 'Team',
    'foreignKey' => 'home_id'
),
'GuestTeam' => array(
    'className' => 'Team',
    'foreignKey' => 'guest_id'
),
);
}
```

In the Team model create association:

```
class Team extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
'HomeMatch' => array(
    'className' => 'Match',
    'foreignKey' => 'home_id'
),
'GuestMatch' => array(
    'className' => 'Match',
    'foreignKey' => 'guest_id'
)      
);
}
```

After find your Team, you have two arrays, one with Home matches, second with Guest matches. You need to merge this two array in one, in order to use in pagination, sorting, etc.

OR use Contanable behavior

```
$matches = $this->Team->find('all', array(
     'contain' => array('Match' => array(
         'conditions' => array(
             'OR' => array(
                 'Match.home_id' => $id,
                 'Match.guest_id' => $id,
             ),
          'order' => 'Match.date ASC'
         )
     ))
));
```

EDIT:

```
class Team extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
 // Or instead of the two associations try just one.
 // I not tested this
'Match' => array(
    'className' => 'Match',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => array(
       'OR' => array(
          'Team.id' =>'Match.home_id',
          'Team.id' =>'Match.guest_id'
       )
    )
),      
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I will give this a shot. I'll read up on containable behaviour as well and see what I can get working.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is a habtm relationship in cake. [See documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Matches and Teams have a n:m relationship. Means 1 Team has many Matches and 1 Match has many teams. 
So just create a join table matches_teams with fields id, match_id, team_id. After this add in your Team and Match model the new habtm relationship like it's descripted in [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Have fun joining your date ;)

Comment: No, one match has only two team :)

Comment: two teams are more than one, so it's many?! In cake it's a habtm or a hasMany through relationship like you suggested ;)

Comment: habtm relationship cannot be used because match has other data, like results, date and time, location_id, etc

Comment: In this case habtm could be used because matches isn't the join table and can have additional data. The join table matches_teams can't have additional data. With your hasMany through solution you would need one table less in your database but I would suggest accessing data is a bit easier with habtm

Comment: Yes you can, but how do select who is home and who is guest team ?

Comment: With an additional field in matches table :p ok your solution is more suitable ;)